# Can't use data from MainViewModel in another ViewModel

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, mvvm, viewmodel

I have a Problem with `MVVM` and `two Views` and corresponding `ViewModels`.

I have a `MainViewModel` and `SettingsViewModel`.

The `MainViewModel` executes on program start reading settings from an xml file.
If I click on a Settings Button in the main view the `SettingsView` will be open with the binding `SettingsViewModel` and should fill the forms with Data.
But the Problem is how can I get the Data from the `MainViewModel` to the `SettingsViewModel`?.

In the `SettingViewModel` I don't have a reference of the `MainViewModel`. How can I get this?

My first idea was to set the Data over the constructor but I can't use the constructor for this because I get the instances of the View with `DataTemplate` in the `App.xaml`:

```
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewmodels:SettingsViewModel}">
          <views:SettingsView/>
        </DataTemplate>
```

My second idea was to solve it with Events. But that didn't work either because I don't get the reference of the `SettingsViewModel` in the `MainViewModel`.

This is my first project using `MVVM` pattern. Maybe it's an understanding problem of mine.

I'm trying to solve this problem since one week and I'm very desperate now.

I created a sample Project on Github for better understanding:
https://github.com/fgth/Example

Please help me - Thank you.

Comment: You could make the SettingsViewModel a property of the MainViewModel. If the MainViewModel reads the settings from a file, it can directly save it to its property SettingsViewModel, which is the DataContext of the SettingsView.

Comment: thank you. I already tried this. The problem is, that i change the Views(usercontrols) with a ContentControl Element. If i change the the view over the ContentControl then there will be creating a new instance of the viewmodel and i don't get this reference.

Comment: The ViewModel should not be changed, it should always be the same instance. If the SettingsView is an element in the MainView, you can bind the SettingsViewModel to the SettingsView with `<SettingsView DataContext="{Binding SettingsViewModel}"/> (assuming the property is named `SettingsViewModel`) to always use the correct instance of the SettingsViewModel.

Comment: I'm using a ContentControl element with a binding to change the views in the mainViewModel. I added a sample Project to my question, there you can see it.

Comment: Option 1 : Either have the settings viewmodel as a property inside the mainviewmodel and invoke it accordingly. Option 2: Create a singleton class to hold the data. Option 3: Setup a IOC container (may be over kill), and register mainviewmodel and settingsviewmodel. Resolve them without any issue.

Comment: There's been a lot of talk of keeping a reference to the SettingsViewModel. However, there are benefits to keeping your View(Model)s as shortlived as possible. Surely when they resemble simple forms, as in this case, you can instantiate a new lifecycle on request.

Comment: I'm not a fan of the Singleton design pattern as it is based on ambient state and hides the actual dependencies of your classes. If you only want one instance of your class, then just create only one. Lastly, I wouldn't advise DI containers to someone getting started with MVVM either. They'll learn a lot more / get better insights constructing the object graph by hand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This is my first project using `MVVM` pattern. Maybe it's an understanding problem of mine.

Your MVVM layering is fine.

- Model: Settings
- ViewModel: SettingsViewModel
- View: SettingsView

Storing / using the `Settings` instance on the parent `MainViewModel` also makes sense.

Your problem is more a static vs instance misunderstanding.

In `SettingsView` you define your `SettingsViewModel` as a static resource. Meaning its default constructor will be called every time a `SettingsView` is resolved.

```xml
<UserControl x:Class="Example.Views.SettingsView"
             ...
             >
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <vms:SettingsViewModel x:Key="settingsvm"/>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </UserControl.Resources>
    <StackPanel DataContext="{StaticResource settingsvm}">
        ...
    </StackPanel>
</UserControl>
```

Given you create a new `Settings` instance in the `SettingsViewModel` constructor, you'll always end up with a blank slate.

```cs
public SettingsViewModel()
{
    Mysettings = new Settings();
    ...
}
```

It would be better to pass the `Settings` instance from the `MainViewModel`  to the `SettingsViewModel` on each request.

```cs
ActualPage = new SettingsViewModel(mysettings);
```

The updated constructor using Dependency Injection.

```cs
public SettingsViewModel(Settings settings)
{
    Mysettings = settings;
    ...
}
```

It wasn't the `DataTemplate` flow that was complaining about the constructor, it just matches types. However, the static resource did require a parameterless constructor, but again we don't need / want that functionality. After updating the `SettingsView` everything should work as expected.

```xml
<UserControl x:Class="Example.Views.SettingsView"
             ...
             >
    <StackPanel>
        <Label Margin="10" Content="TestView" HorizontalAlignment= "Center" FontSize="20"/>
        <Label Margin="10" Content="TextBox" HorizontalAlignment= "Center"/>
        <TextBox Width="200" Margin="0" Text="{Binding Mysettings.TextOfSetting}"/>
    </StackPanel>
</UserControl>
```

Note we let the `DataContext` flow through implicitly, which is (often) a sign of good design.

Comment: thank you so much. Now everything is working fine.